# Getting VerifyCsrfToken Trying to get property of non-object when middleware added

Tags: laravel

I am adding a middleware that checks for a specific right from database

Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $right = User_access_right::where('access_key','=','add')
        ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
        ->first();

    if(count($right) == 1)
    {
        if($right->access_value == 1)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->to('/home')->withErrors(['status' => 'You do not have privilege to do such task']);
    }
}
```

Now in controller I have added to some of the methods.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('hasAddPrivilege', ['only'=>['CreateCategory', 'CreateSubCategory']]);
    }
```

And in VerifyCsrfToken.php I'm adding some routes to not check the token

```
protected $except = [
    '/category/create',
    '/category/update',
    '/category/sub_create',
    '/category/move_category',
    '/item/create',
    '/item/update'
];
```

And my routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => '/category'],     function()
{
Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@Category');
Route::post('/create', 'CategoryController@CreateCategory');
Route::post('/update', 'CategoryController@UpdateCategory');
Route::post('/sub_create', 'CategoryController@CreateSubCategory');
Route::get('/other_category/{id}', 'CategoryController@getRestOfCategories');
Route::post('/move_category', 'CategoryController@MoveCategory');
Route::get('/getCategoryTree', 'CategoryController@getCategoryTree');
});
```

But still I am getting this error;

> > ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 156: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware has a logical branch that doesn't return anything at all. Middleware need to return a response so the previous middleware can do things with the response if needed. They take a request and return a response.

`VerifyCsrfToken` is getting a `null` as the response from your middleware because nothing was returned at all.

It is also possible the next middleware after this one isn't returning a response correctly and that is being returned back which would cause the same issue.

```
if(count($right) == 1)
{
    if($right->access_value == 1)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    // what about when $right->access_value != 1 ?
}
```

Comment: OMG!... I've been doing Laravel since 2 years and I didn't see this blunder. Gotta sleep now.

Comment: we have all been there ... get some sleep :)

Comment: Cheers mate. Much appreciated!